# Use 'Show Touches' programatically in Android

Tags: android, permissions, touch, settings, system

I would like to use Show Touches in my 6.0+ app.
I found a way to turn it on:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "show_touches", 1); // 0 for turn it off
```

I requested permission to modify system settings:

```
if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext()))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
}
```

The permission is granted successfully, but when I try to use the "show_touches" setting I always get an exception that I can't change private secure settings. But if I would like to change the brigness for example, I can make it successfully without exception.

I have read that this some kind of bug in Marshmallow that you can't use this setting. Does this really true? Could you please help me how can I use this feature anyway?

Regards, Stanley.

P.S.: I made it on 5.0 and it worked perfectly, but unfortunatelly I would need to make this to work on 6.0+ as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. I downgraded the "targetSdkVersion" to 22 from 23 and it works now.